# Hive - create an external table from an existing table

Tags: hive, hiveql, hadoop2

Hive - create an external table from an existing table, if it can't be done... is there a work around.

The hive version I am using is : `Hive 1.2.1000.2.4.2.0-258`

The query that I wanted to run is something as follows...

```
create external table table_1
stored as orc
location'wasb://vnextdev@1vnextstorage.blob.core.windows.net/output/table_1/'
tblproperties ("orc.compress"="SNAPPY")
as 
select * from table_0 limit 0;
```

---

At cwiki they explain as

CTAS has these restrictions:

```
The target table cannot be a partitioned table.
The target table cannot be an external table.
The target table cannot be a list bucketing table.
```

Copying the link below.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableAsSelect%28CTAS%29

Thank You :-)

Comment: are you getting any error while running above query?

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to create a hive table with `like` keyword

```
create table target_table like source_table;
```